# Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

Applications using angular6 and node.js ran into a problem, which is now writing the part that is responsible for uploading pictures on the server, created the imagePreview = "" variable (yes, it is empty by default)

`ERROR in src/app/categories-page/categories-form/categories-form.component.ts(74,7): error TS2322: Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
[1]   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

That's what I have on line 74, I don’t understand where the error is (WebStorm emphasizes `reader.result`)

```
reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = reader.result
    }
```

Please tell me how to fix

The code of the component that is responsible for downloading images:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from "@angular/router";
import {FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {CategoriesService} from "../../shared/services/categories.service";
import {switchMap} from "rxjs/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs";
import {MaterialService} from "../../shared/classes/material.service";
import {Category} from "../../shared/interfaces";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-categories-form',
  templateUrl: './categories-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./categories-form.component.css']
})
export class CategoriesFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('input') inputRef: ElementRef
  form: FormGroup
  image: File
  imagePreview=''
  isNew= true
  category: Category

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form=new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })

    this.form.disable()

    this.route.params
      .pipe(
        switchMap(
          (params: Params)=>{
            if(params['id']){
              this.isNew=false
              return this.categoriesService.getById(params['id'])
            }
            return of (null)
          }
        )
      )
      .subscribe(
        (category: Category)=>{
          if(category){
            this.category = category
            this.form.patchValue({
              name: category.name
            })
            this.imagePreview=category.imageSrc
            MaterialService.updateTextInputs()
          }

          this.form.enable()
        },
        error=>MaterialService.toast(error.error.message)
      )
  }

  triggerClick(){
    this.inputRef.nativeElement.click()
  }

  onFileUpload(event: any){
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    this.image = file

    const reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = reader.result as string
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }

  onSubmit(){

    let obs$

    this.form.disable()

    if(this.isNew){
      obs$ = this.categoriesService.create(this.form.value.name, this.image)
    } else {
      obs$ = this.categoriesService.update(this.category._id, this.form.value.name, this.image)
    }

    obs$.subscribe(
      category =>{
        this.category = category
        MaterialService.toast('Изменения сохранены!')
        this.form.enable()
      },

      error=>{
        MaterialService.toast(error.error.message)
        this.form.enable()
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Create and edit

```
create(name: string, image?:File) : Observable<Category>{
    const fd = new FormData()

    if(image){
      fd.append('image', image.name)
    }

    fd.append('name', name)
    return this.http.post<Category>('/api/category', fd)
  }

  update(id: string, name: string, image?:File) : Observable<Category>{

    const fd= new FormData()
    if(image){
      fd.append('image', image.name)
    }
    fd.append('name', name)
    return this.http.patch<Category>(`/api/category/${id}`, fd)
  }
```

Comment: well, `reader.result` is a `string | ArrayBuffer` and `this.imagePreview` is a `string`. You haven't provided enough information for anyone to know what `reader` is. If it's a `ReadbleStream` or similar, make sure it's finished reading and either dump it to string or force its typing to string: `reader.result as string`

Comment: @joh04667 I changed a little now, now the line has the form `this.imagePreview = reader.result as string` Yes, now it does not give an error, but the problem is that the variable `imagePreview` it transmits empty, and must transmit a link to the image

Comment: Sounds like it's still an `ArrayBuffer`, hence the tuple typing. You need to decode it first

Comment: @joh04667 With this difficult, I just started to study, I will try to update the question now and add the code that is responsible for downloading pictures

Answer (score 1):

ArrayBuffer as string may result in data truncation (would have to test).
So you have to explicitly cast it, as to tell the compiler "*I know what I am doing*".

Try this, it works for me:

```
reader.onload = () => {
    this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
}
```